# Markdown: Reference to section from another file

Tags: markdown

I have two markdown files: a `parent.md` and a `child.md`.

So `parent.md`:

```
# Main section

## sub-section
```

I'd like to make reference to `## sub-section` from `child.md`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 76):

In `MarkDown`, reference is possible using hyperlink :

```
#  Main section

##  [sub-section](./child.md#sub-section)    
##  [sub-section](/child.md#sub-section)
##  [sub-section](child.md#sub-section)
```

Unfortunately the direct embedding of another Markdown file is not possible

## Alternatives

An alternative is the use of an incision from a capture of the other file:

```
#  Main section

##  sub-section

![ImageTheOtherMarkdown](Screent.png)
```

Comment: If you have a section that has uppercase words, change them to lowercase for the link. Spaces also become dashes. For example, if the section was called Sub Section1, it would be [sub-section1](./child.md#sub-section1)

Answer (score 21):

What worked for me is in parent.md:

```
[link](./file.md#section-name) // note the dash!
```

In child.md:

```
## ...
## section name
```

I tested this on my local via JetBrains IDE.

Comment: This works in VSCode and in mkdocs. As [maraps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15201180/maraps) pointed out, the section names in the target are slugified with dashes.

Comment: It is not IDE specific. It works with an LPS, for example with [marksman](https://github.com/artempyanykh/marksman)

Answer (score 0):

[The snippets macro](https://facelessuser.github.io/pymdown-extensions/extensions/snippets/) gets quite close to that function I've asked to add support to importing particular lines from files on manually setting anchors on one files and then injecting the anchor section in another file

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34633126)