# Inner link after link

Tags: markdown

In markdown, I want to redirect to other file in same folder.
And also, it must go to middle of page.
So I tried:

```
[TITLE](./filename.md#5.-fifth)
```

but it redirects to top of page, how can I do this?

In filename.md, ,

```
# Title
## 1. First subtitle
## 2. ....
...
## 5. fifth <<- i want to go here
```

Comment: sample `filename.md` missing

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are expecting a `##` subhead to be an anchor you can link to. That is not a markdown feature. Some specific markdown implementations, such as GitHub, might do that for you; but it is not part of the markdown standard and you must not expect *your* markdown to do it.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is right. It really boils down to your flavor of MarkDown, and where you're using it.

For example, I use VSCode with a couple of extensions for my MD files and it recognized the link flawlessly. So I tried putting the files on
[GitHub](https://github.com/tajaddini/sandbox)
to see how it'd work out. It looks like the dot `.` in your section name is causing problems. So, I'd suggest trying a different naming/numbering method.

For the sake of completeness,
[here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51207259/6942707) also a complete answer.